# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day,

I have received the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])` 
for the library jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2

Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').closest('.panel-heading').addClass('active-faq');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"] .panel-title span').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>');
    });
    $('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').closest('.panel-heading').removeClass('active-faq');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"] .panel-title span').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>');
    });
});
```

I am using the latest Jquery CDN

```
<!-- Javascript and Jquery files -->
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: None of the code you've shown produces that selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` is a special character and needs to be escaped like:

```
'a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])'
```

Source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2885

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do you seem to have an extra `#` in your selector.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89xntp9w/) for a working example